# 'SKView?' does not have a member named 'bounds'

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have recently come up to an error with a code and want to fix this. It is swift coded and I hope you guys are able to help me with this.

The error says:
'SKView?' does not have a member named 'bounds'

If you could help me with this as this is my first swift app, I would love you forever :)

Here are the code for the "title" of this question.

```
overlay = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.grayColor(), size: self.view.bounds.size)
```

Comment: You need to reduce this to the minimum amount of code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Is the edit good enough for that?
There is multiple of the same error but with different members everywhere in the code.

Comment: The edit makes it clearer, but that is still a TON of code in the question, most of which doesn't deal with 'view' at all. In general, the less code you post, the easier it is for us to find the problem with it. You should always try to isolate the minimum amount of code needed to fully represent a problem.

Comment: does it look better now? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SKView?` does not have a property of type `bounds` (note the `?`), but `SKView!` might.

In the first example, and the one you are getting an error on, you are not implicitly unwrapping the optional. To do this, use the `!` operator.

`self.view!.bounds.size` will yield the correct type. Note the use of the `!` operator to unwrap the optional.

**Edit:** You have many of the same errors here. The tipoff is in the error message. Anything along the lines of `<x> does not have member named <y>` is a similar error.

Comment: Or optionally unwrap it, like `self.view?.bounds.size`, assuming the `SKSpriteNode` initializer can take a `nil` size.

Comment: That removed my FIRST error. Is there any way that i might contact you so you maybe can help me with the rest of my code?
I now have 34 more errors :)

Comment: Okay I have fixed most of them now I think.
I still have 9 Errors.

Comment: @StigPing Those seem to be different types of errors and merit their own questions. Be careful and do your research before asking.

Comment: @StigPing No Problem. Glad to do so